# Are finite element mesh considered as planar graph?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, finite-element-method

Planar graphs have the intersection of edges only at nodes. So the finite element mesh also satisfies the definition of planar graph. Should we consider a FE mesh as a planar graph?
I am trying to solve a 2D problem. I want to mesh a rectangular domain in which at least 80% of the mesh elements should be heptagons. But according to Euler's formula in graph theory shows that its not possible to do so.

Comment: This depends where it came from! If it comes from a 2D problem, it should be planar.

Comment: What for? Letters on this page can be considered as planar graphs too, but what's the purpose?

Comment: It is a 2D problem. I want to mesh a rectangular domain in which at least 80% of the mesh elements should be heptagons. But according to Euler's formula in graph theory shows that its not possible to do so.

Comment: Related (from same user): [Can we mesh a rectangle using only heptagons?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2950094/856)

Comment: How are you going to define the finite element shape functions of a heptagon? And why not simply subdivide the heptagons into standard linear triangles?

Comment: @HandeBruijn I am using wachspress shape function for heptagons. I don't want to divide the polygon into triangle, infact I am trying to solve the problem using each hepatgon as a single finite element. This may result into reduction into computation cost in terms of time.

Comment: Having seen some references for those wachspress shape functions, I'd rather be happy with linear triangles, but it's your choice.